# Overflowing comment text not in alignment

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to achieve following layout
[image]

There is profile picture, followed by username and followed by comment.But if the comment is too long it should starting coming below the username and not from the profile picture.

Following is my code

```
Row(
                              children: [
                                const CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                      'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTTul_FjIE5w2p_VarQyzwaZ1mkOYjQRXcNCA&usqp=CAU'),
                                  radius: 16,
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  width: 10,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'UserName',
                                  style: GoogleFonts.tenorSans(
                                      color: Colors.black),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'The Dram Club is a platform that endeavours to bring whisky enthusiassts & aficionados together for people to enjoy their whiskes',
                                  style: GoogleFonts.tenorSans(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                                )

                              ],
                            )
```

For the above code the comment text gets cuts off if its large so instead of using `Row` I decided to use `Wrap` but that is moving my enter comment in a new Row. I just tried wrapping the username and comment text in a `Wrap` but nothing happens. I tried using `Flexible` and `Expanded` widget as well

Comment: Can you please add your screen shot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code.

```
Row(
      children: [
        const CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
              'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTTul_FjIE5w2p_VarQyzwaZ1mkOYjQRXcNCA&usqp=CAU'),
          radius: 16,
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          width: 10,
        ),

        Flexible(
          child: RichText(
            text: TextSpan(
              children: <TextSpan>[
                TextSpan(text: 'Username ', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black)),
                TextSpan(text: 'The Dram Club is a platform that endeavours to bring whisky enthusiassts & aficionados together for people to enjoy their whiskes', style: TextStyle( color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )

      ],
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [RichText class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html), in this you can add multiple text with different styles. So the idea is

> To have a single text, with different styles, one for `UserName` and other for `Comment`

```
children: [
   CircleAvatar(
     backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTTul_FjIE5w2p_VarQyzwaZ1mkOYjQRXcNCA&usqp=CAU'),
     radius: 16,
   ),
   SizedBox(
      width: 10,
   ),
   // here for User name and Comment
   RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        text: 'UserName ',  // <-- Username text
        style: GoogleFonts.tenorSans(color: Colors.black),  // <-- User name style
        children: <TextSpan>[
          // your comment code
          TextSpan(text: 'The Dram Club is a platform that endeavours to bring whisky enthusiassts & aficionados together for people to enjoy their whiskes', 
            style: GoogleFonts.tenorSans(color: Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)))
        ]
      )  
   )
]
```